# É possivel deixar parte de imagem transparente com css?

Tags: css

É possivel fazer um gradiente da foto para transparente na parte de baixo de uma imagem usando apenas css ?

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dei uma editada na minha resposta com mais uma opção usando filtros e blends, ficou interessante depois olha lá. []´s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da para fazer algo parecido usando uma mistura de Filtros e Blend Modes, porem a extremidade da imagem nunca vai ficar 100% transparente.

Aqui tem um exemplo da técnica aplica, que precisa de ajustes para ficar dentro do seu *"padrão de aceitação"*... (imagem tratada e original ao lado).

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/11/11);
}
* {
    float: left;
}
.cont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cont .branco {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.cont .mix {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: opacity(40%);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.cont .normalizer {
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
}
.cont .filtros {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: contrast(120%) brightness(110%) opacity(50%);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <img class="mix"src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="">
    <img class="mix normalizer"src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="">
    <img class="filtros"src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="">
    <div class="branco"></div>
</div>

<img src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="">
```

Uma solução é usando ***dois backgrounds em uma div***, porém só funciona com cores sólidas. Vc vai simular um sombreado sobre a imagem que deve ter a mesma cor que o fundo. No exemplo usei preto.

Veja o resultado.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.holder {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), url(http://placecage.com/300/300);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder"></div>
```

***Já para fazer esse "fade" realmente transparente, acho que por CSS ainda não é possível.***

**OBS1:** Considere usar um **.PNG**, é fácil fazer isso em qq editor de imagens! Pois nem tudo vale a pena fazer com CSS, essa mistura de `filtros` com `blends` faz a página perder a performance e é acelerado por hardware...

**OBS2:** Tecnicas e suporde dos Browsers. `Filter` não é aceito pelo IE https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters e o `Mix-Blend-Mode` não é aceito nem pelo IE nem pelo Edge https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode